# Obtain launch command for application from its icon returned by dash app lens

Tags: startup, unity-dash

What is the general way to find out the command used by the dash app lens to launch an app from its corresponding icon?

I'm in the habit of clicking on the Ubuntu icon in the upper left corner (which I believe is called the "dash app lens") and typing the generic name of an application (such as "skype") to launch the application by clicking on its icon returned from the resulting search.

However, if I want to add an application via the "Startup Applications Preferences" I need to know the command used by the dash app lens when clicking on the application's icon.  For skype that's easy enough as its simply "skype", but not everything is that simple.

Comment: One way to find the command is to look into the .desktop files in /usr/share/applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find almost all software shortcuts that appear in Dash in `/usr/share/applications` directory.

If you right-click a `.desktop` file and select "properties" you will see the command that is executed, when you click on the icon in Dash.